# receiving error 0xc000000e booting into Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, boot

While in Windows 10 Pro, I used 'msconfig' to change SELECTIVE STARTUP to NORMAL STARTUP. When I rebooted my PC it no longer boots into WINDOWS 10, and it receives error '0xc000000e'. I can, however, use a rescue disk to boot to the COMMAND prompt. Can I use the COMMAND prompt to boot to my Windows 10 Pro OS or is there a better way?

Comment: If you can boot to Safe mode, that would be the better way to enter Selective Startup and find what is causing the issue: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-start-windows-10-in-safe-mode